# I18n working everywhere but not in contentComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I followed an [example](https://github.com/appfoundry/react-native-multi-language-sample) that uses I18n to implement multi-language. Everything was working fine until I tried to use the I18n on a sideMenu. I create a drawer with DrawerNavigator and set the SideMenu as contentComponent

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      path: '/',
      screen: WelcomeContainer,
    },
    Category: {
      path: '/other',
      screen: other,
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#4edb6d',
    },
  }
);
```

In sideMenu I use I18n exactly as in the other components

```
<Text>
{ I18n.t('menu.title') }
</Text>
```

Even if I change the language the text is always in English which is the default language. The text language changed one time after multiple language change. Do you have an idea about the problem or how to solve it?

**Edit:**
I just noticed that the text language change only after I click on an item from the sideMenu. Any idea?